# specify different subsets or intervals of a variable in the by argument of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Using the following reaction time data (simplified for demonstrative purposes):

```
>dt
   subject trialnum blockcode values.trialtype latency correct
1        1        1  practice        cueswitch    3020       1
2        1        1      test           cuerep    4284       1
3        1       21      test        cueswitch    2094       1
4        1       34      test           cuerep    3443       1
5        1       50      test       taskswitch    3313       1
6        2        1  practice        cueswitch    3020       1
7        2        1      test           cuerep    1109       1
8        2       21      test        cueswitch    3470       1
9        2       34      test           cuerep    2753       1
10       2       50      test       taskswitch    3321       1
```

I have been using data.table to obtain reaction time variables for consecutive subsets of trials (specified by trialnum, which ranges from 1 to 170 in the full dataset):

```
dt1=dt[blockcode=="test" & correct==1, list(
RT1=.SD[trialnum>=1 & trialnum<=30 & values.trialtype=="cuerep", mean(latency)],
RT2=.SD[trialnum>=31 & trialnum<=60 & values.trialtype=="cuerep", mean(latency)]
), by="subject"]
```

The output is

```
   subject     RT1     RT2
1:       1    4284    3443
2:       2    1109    2753
```

However, it becomes tedious creating a variable for each subset when there are more than 2 or 3 subsets. How can I specify those subsets more efficiently?

Comment: You need to provide more complete example data, and better example of what your expected outcome is.

Comment: My guess is that you are looking something along these lines right? (df1 <- dt[dt$subject == 1,]);
(df2 <- df1[df1$blockcode == "test",]);
(df3 <- df2[df2$correct == 1,]);
(df4 <- df3[df3$trialnum %in% c(1, 30),]);
(df5 <- df4[df4$values.trialtype == "cuerepetition",]);

Comment: Not quite. I'm looking for a more automated way of generating RT variables for N subsets of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findInterval` or `cut` to subset your `trialnum` column`

An example

```
# set the key to use binary search
setkey(dt, blockcode,correct,values.trialtype)
# the subset you want
dt1 <- dt[.('test',1,'cuerepetition')]

# use cut  to define subsets

dt2 <- dt1[,list(latency = mean(latency)),
     by=list(subject, trialset = cut(trialnum,seq(0,180,by=30)))]
dt2
#    subject trialset latency
# 1:       1   (0,30]    4284
# 2:       1  (30,60]    3443
# 3:       2   (0,30]    1109
# 4:       2  (30,60]    2753

#If you want separate columns, it is a simple as using `dcast`
library(reshape2)

dcast(dt2,subject~trialset, value.var = 'latency')
#   subject (0,30] (30,60]
# 1       1   4284    3443
# 2       2   1109    2753
```

Comment: This is close, but the challenge for me is creating a separate column/variable for each subset as shown in the output (crepRT1,crepRT2... and many more in the real data) without actually typing out each variable.

Comment: Should have realized that myself as I know dcast. Thanks, this works very well and is convenient.